# How to move arbitrary elements into sidebar responsively using CSS

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a layout where there are N block elements.
These elements stack vertically (as is expected for block elements), this is what I desire for small-screens... however, on larger screens I want to move some of the elements to a sidebar (using CSS only). I'm thinking *maybe* this is possible with display grid? or some other mix of CSS techniques?

Here is a snippet.. the styling is just to give some color to the divs and show how I'd like it to look.

```css
.want-to-look-like,
.container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1em;
}

.content div,
.container div {
  background-color: #fee;
}
.sidebar div.can-sidebar,
.container div.can-sidebar {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.want-to-look-like {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar {
  flex-basis: 20%;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class='can-sidebar'>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class='can-sidebar'>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class='can-sidebar'>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>

I want the above HTML structure to be styled so it looks like this (on screens wider than 800px, otherwise it would just stay as-is):

<div class='want-to-look-like'>
  <div class='content'>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
  </div>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    <div class='can-sidebar'>...</div>
    <div class='can-sidebar'>...</div>
    <div class='can-sidebar'>...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So, the first chunk of HTML (above) is what the HTML structure is.. but on screens larger than 800px I want it to look like the second chunk of HTML (above) having the content/sidebar layout.

I **could** create a bunch of grid-areas and specifically place each div in its desired grid area(s). However, **I'm hoping for some way where I don't have to specify locations for each div manually** - rather, divs could be added (dynamically) and they will show in the content or sidebar automatically simply by adding the appropriate class attribute.

Comment: Please edit the question and use the snippet tool `<>` to load your html and css.  We need to see what you have done so far.

Comment: @RohitGupta I have added a runnable snippet. However, all my attempts at achieving my goal have either failed or required manually specifying locations for each div - so I don't have anything to show for "what I have done so far" (sadly).

Comment: I'm thinking maybe what I want is **not** possible? However there is a lot of clever CSS out there so thought I'd ask (my searches failed to find an answer). Having a solution for this scenario would be convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the elements to go to the first or second column.
flow dense is needed to avoid leaving holes:

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 150px 80px;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
  
}

.container div {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: black 1px solid;
    grid-column: 1;
}

.container div.can-sidebar {
    background-color: yellow;
    grid-column: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class='can-sidebar'>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class='can-sidebar'>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class='can-sidebar'>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent, that did it. I didn't know about grid-auto-flow:dense. Thanks.